# How far in advance can I apply for Irish Visa

Tags: visas, ireland

I'm planning a trip to Ireland in October. How far in advance can I apply for a visa?
The official web site says `Prepare your application 3 months before you travel`. But does it mean I can do it earlier? For example, I applied for US visa about 6 months before the actual trip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you can apply 3 months before your intended travel date http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Visit%20Tourist You can’t apply earlier than 3 months. Providing proof of travel arrangements is not required when applying and you are not obliged to stick to travelling on the intended date once you receive your visa.